# Java, BigDecimal. Problems with division

Tags: java, division, bigdecimal

I'm trying to calculate a percentage "factor". That is, given a 20%, convert it into 0.2 (my intention is to later multiply values by that and get the 20% of the values).

Anyway, the question is related with this piece of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int roundingMode = BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR;
    BigDecimal hundred = new BigDecimal("100");
    BigDecimal percentageFactor = null;
    BigDecimal percentage = new BigDecimal("20");
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("500");
    percentageFactor = percentage.divide(hundred, roundingMode);
    float f = percentage.floatValue() / hundred.floatValue();
    f = value.floatValue() * f;
    BigDecimal aux = value.multiply(percentageFactor);
    System.out.println("factor:"+percentageFactor.toString());
    System.out.println("final falue:"+aux.toString());
    System.out.println("Float Value:"+f);       
}
```

I would expect the outcome of this to be something like:

```
factor: 0.2
final value: 100
float value: 100
```

but instead `percentage.divide(hundred, roundingMode);` is returning zero, an hence I get:

```
factor:0
final falue:0
Float Value:100.0
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I divide two big decimals properly?

By the way, I'm using `BigDecimal` because I will be calculating monetary percentages, so I want control regarding rounding.

Answer (score 17):

I think that the best solution is to set the requested scale when dividing: In this case perhaps 2.

```
    var hundred = new BigDecimal(100);
    var percentage = new BigDecimal(20);
    var value = new BigDecimal(500);
    
    var percentageFactor = 
        percentage.divide(hundred,2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    
    value = value.multiply(percentageFactor);
    System.out.println("final value:"+ value);
```

Final value: `100.00`

The multiplication is using the scale from the factors (0+2) but it can be specified too.

I'd use `ROUND_HALF_UP` for accounting (in my legislation) or `ROUND_EVEN` (for statistics) for rounding mode.

Answer (score 9):

The scale of `new BigDecimal("20")` is zero because you've got no decimal point in there. That means that your `percentage.divide(hundred, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR)` will produce zero (it's effectively `int(20/100)` or `0`).

If you really want to do fractional stuff, use `new BigDecimal("20.00")` so the scale is set correctly, or use one of the other constructors to set the scale specifically.

Here's the output from that simple change of `20` to `20.00`, complete with your spellink misteak :-)

```
factor:0.20
final falue:100.00
Float Value:100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

float has only 6 digits of accuracy and is almost never a good choice, I would suggest you use double instead. (or BigDecimal can be better in some cases)

Comment: If you want control over rounding, you shouldn't be using floating-point numbers at all, neither float nor double. Stick with BigDecimal.

Comment: Often only the final result needs to have controlled rounding, so you have used BigDecimal just for rounding the result (or a simple helper method) This can be significantly simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `factor` is 0 instead of 0.2 in your code is because

1. you've set the RoundingMode to be FLOOR (which means ROUND DOWN), and
2. your `percentage` variable has an implicit scale of 0 (any `BigDecimal`s initialised from round number without specifying scale will have scale of 0)

So when you call divide you are rounding down any decimals and you are maintaining a scale of 0, and hence 0.2 is rounded down to 0.

To get the correct number, you can either

1. specify the scale explicitly, or
2. since you know you are dividing against 100, you can just use the `BigDecimal#divide(BigDecimal)` method instead (without providing scale or RoundingMethod). In your case, the method will not throw `ArithmeticException` since there is no possibility of non-terminating decimals (think 20 / 100 = 0.2, 20 / 10000 = 0.002 - decimals always terminate when dividing by 100).

However, if you're dividing against another number say 3 then you need to specify the scale because there is a possibility of non-terminating decimals (think 10 / 3 = 3.3333333333...)